# Dataframe is only taking first 50 rows of my csv no matter specified length

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to take my CSV into a dataframe so that I can process it easier, but for some reason the frame is only including the first 50 lines of my csv even when specified 10, 500, 100000, etc (csv is 2gb, very long)

`df = pd.read_csv('all_reverse_key_passages.csv')`

only took the first 50, so i added a length parameter:

`df = pd.read_csv('all_reverse_key_passages.csv', nrows = 100)`

this still only returns a length of 50, if nrows is less than 50 then it decreases appropriately.

In variable explorer, I can see the dataframe has a length of 50, and len(df) also returns 50.

Comment: Can you post line 50 and 51? That way we can see if there is bad data or and eof indicator of some sort causing the error.

Comment: I'm not sure how to post the lines as they're in an excel sheet, but as far as I can tell there are no bad data or EOL characters.

Comment: you can use sed to output lines 50 and 51 `sed -n 50,51p /path/to/file`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
df = pd.read_csv('all_reverse_key_passages.csv', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, error_bad_lines=False)
```

Try running these. One probable cause for your problem is that there is some bad data on line 51 which results in pandas stopping the read function.

Comment: So my last test was at a length of 10. When I implemented your suggestion, it defaulted to 10 lines. This makes me think that at some point, when I set it to a length of 50, it got "stuck"? Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: That should not happen but you can try to restart your kernel and try again.